# Wordpress: Pagination not working with custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I see there are so many questions already about custom post type pagination on here, but none of the answers quite seem to be helping me.

I have created a "Testimonials" custom post type and I am now trying to add pagination to it using code that I have had success with for standard Wordpress posts, but it's not quite cooperating right with this.

Now, it's all being built as a shortcode, so everything has to be put into $output and then returned.

Here's what I have:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'testimonial',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => $a['orderby'],
    'order' => $a['order'],
    'posts_per_page' => $testimonials_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$testimonials = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $testimonials->have_posts() ) :
    while( $testimonials->have_posts() ) :
        $output = '...'
        // BLAH BLAH BLAH, YADA YADA YADA...
    endwhile;

    $next_posts_link = '<span class="testimonial_pagination_next">' . get_next_posts_link($next_text) . '</span>';
    if(get_previous_posts_link()){
        $next_posts_link = '<span class="testimonial_prev_next_separator">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="testimonial_pagination_next">' . get_next_posts_link($next_text) . '</span>';
        $prev_posts_link = '<span class="testimonial_pagination_prev">' . get_previous_posts_link($prev_text) . '</span>';
    } else {
        $prev_posts_link = "";
    }

    $output .= '<div class="testimonial_pagination_links">';
    $output .= $prev_posts_link;
    $output .= $next_posts_link;
    $output .= '</div>';

    wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
    $testimonialsOutput .= 'No testimonials to display';
endif;

return $output;
```

At first glance it appears that it's not working at all.
    http://sandbox.graphicdetail.co.nz/testimonials-pagination-test/

However, if I go to page 2, http://sandbox.graphicdetail.co.nz/testimonials-pagination-test/page/2/
I find that the "Prev" link is working fine.  Same with page 3, 4 and so on.  So it appears that `get_previous_posts_link()` is working fine, but `get_next_posts_link()` isn't.

That seems weird to me, that one should work but not the other.

If I use this code:

```
$big = 999999999;
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' =>  $testimonials->max_num_pages
) );
```

Then that works fine and displays, "« Previous 1 2 3 4 Next »" fine and it all works.  However, I want to use `get_previous_posts_link()` and `get_next_posts_link()` so that I can control the text that gets displayed as the "Prev" and "Next" links as well as the wrapping elements around them.

EDIT:
By request, here is the post type registration code that I'm using:

```
function testimonials_posttype_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Testimonials', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Testimonial', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Testimonial'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Testimonial'),
        'new_item' => __('New Testimonial'),
        'view_item' => __('View Testimonial'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Testimonial'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url('img/testimonials-icon.png',__FILE__ ),
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title','excerpt','editor','thumbnail','revisions')
      );

    register_post_type( 'testimonial' , $args );
}

add_action('init', 'testimonials_posttype_register');
```

Comment: Can you add in your `register_post_type` args as well? I think the problem may be coming from a setting there, but I'm unable to confirm without seeing them.

Comment: Have added as edit to end of post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see part of the problem: [get_previous_posts_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_posts_link/) does not return anything if `is_single()` is true. So if you are using this shortcode on singular posts, the link isn't going to show up. Same thing for `get_next_posts_link`.

I'd suggest using the `next_text` and `prev_text` args of [paginate links](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) in order to solve this. You can set the `type` arg to `array`, and then grab the first and last items in the array to avoid using the "1 2 3 4" links as well.

Comment: Thanks jhned - This is being used on a page, not a post.  But in any case, I hadn't considered using `'type' => 'array'` in my `paginate_links()` args.  That does appear to be working nicely.  Thanks.

Comment: Part of the annoying thing about WordPress is the terminology and how "post" gets reused in a lot of contexts. A page is a post with the page post type. A post is a post with the post post type. An attachment is a post with the attachment post type. By "singular post" I meant "any individual post of any post type, rather than an archive page." Sorry for the confusion  on that.